# MFC modeless dialog with style child

Tags: mfc, sdi, modeless-dialog

I have SDI structure program and I want to create `CDialog` with child style and use `CFormView` as its parent. Because I want to use `CFormView` as a "containter".

Now I encounter two problems.

1. I can not set setmunu to `CDialog` (because of the dialog style is child)
2. The dialog behave unnormal (the dialog has `CEdit`, but it can not input ...)

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I create dialog with style popup , after creation,repoint its parent to cformview and solve the above problems.

```
void CFuturePCMSView::DialogCreate()
{
    m_pDlgUser = new CDlgUser(this);
    m_pDlgUser->SetParent(this);
    m_pDlgUser->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```